# programmatically set columns of a tables when populating from a list

Tags: django, django-tables2

I am going to populate a `django-tables2` list from a list and I am following the tutorial example:

```
import django_tables2 as tables

data = [
    {'name': 'Bradley'},
    {'name': 'Stevie'},
]

class NameTable(tables.Table):
    name = tables.Column()

table = NameTable(data)
```

My problem is that I do not know which are the fields needed, so it would be nice for me to be able to specify them at runtime from a list of names. E.g.,:

```
needed_columns = ["name"]
class NameTable(tables.Table):
    for field in needed_columns:
        ADD_FIELD(field, tables.Column())
```

Is this possible in some way??

Answer (score 0):

django-tables2's `Table` has a contructor argument `extra_columns`:

> `extra_columns` (`str`, Column) – list of (name, column)-tuples
>   containing extra columns to add to the instance.

You could use that to dynamically add columns while instantiating a table:

```
class MyTable(tables.Table):
    name = tables.Column()

table = MyTable(data, extra_columns=[
    ('country', tables.Column())
])
```

You can have a look at [how that is implemented](https://github.com/bradleyayers/django-tables2/blob/master/django_tables2/tables.py#L251-L255) to to see how to add columns to a table class.